# How to intercept data between a port and an application in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock, ports

Is there a way to take data from a port, then feed it back to the program using that port in Windows (C,C++,C#)?

Can sockets or pipes be used to detour the data from the port to my program then back to the application?

Comment: Yes and no, it depends what you want. You can use a socket to receive datagrams or accept connections (assuming no other program is listening) on a port. But you cannot easily plug yourself in between another program and the socket it uses, if that is what you want. That, too, is _possible_, but not as easy, and not using a socket.

Comment: [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463267.aspx)

Comment: Are you assuming that the client end (the one initiating the connection) is code under your control, and can cooperate with what you're trying to do? Or are you intercepting communication from third-party code not under your control?

Comment: @Damon Plugging myself in between is what I need to do (or, what i think i need to do). Do you have an idea of how to do it?

Comment: Using the link posted by Jerry Coffin, or by using WinPcap, for example.

Comment: @JoeWhite This would be completely third party.

Comment: @Damon I looked into WFP thoroughly, it's a nightmare to use for this due to certificate signing (Microsoft's sample code wouldn't even run).. I have used a WinPcap .NET wrapper before, but it's my understanding that it copies packets but will not stop them from reaching whatever program there destined for.